# Error No Script Specified when using JPA Persistence Schema Generation

Tags: jpa, database-schema, persistence.xml

Running on Wildly 8.2.0.Final. I get the following error when trying to generate a database schema from a script.

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Schema generation configuration indicated to include CREATE scripts, but no script was specified

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"


 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_mavenFlowChartDB5_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/postgresql</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="META-INF/drop-script.sql"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="META-INF/create-script.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Where the create script is located:
/src/main/resources/META-INF/create-script.sql

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The Wildfly persistence schema generator gui creates incorrect property names for the drop and create targets.

The correct property names are

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/drop-script.sql"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/create-script.sql"/>
```

change create-script to create-script-source and drop-script to drop-script-source

source: https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox